# Is it possible to save computer id upon website sign up?

Tags: ip

I am looking for a solution to stop multiple sign ups on an upcoming websites of mine, but I am looking for different alternatives besides IP saving and tracing that. 
So I was thinking about computer ID saving on the server. Is that possible?

Comment: Some sort of ID, Just I name I used cause I didn't know about anything better..

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible simply because this information is never sent on the network. The only information you could reliably get from a user visiting your website is his IP address in addition to the standard HTTP headers which might or not contain information about the UserAgent he is using, the language he configured in his browser, ...

Comment: There's a pretty interesting project called [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) on the topic.

Comment: I'll check it out, but how does Internet Explorer find Windows Microsoft versions in some of there services?